# Remove array elements using LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, linq

can we remove array elements from `string[]` array if array elements NOT starts from `'%'`

```
string[] saBytesReceived = null; 
bDataReceived = new byte[bBytesToRead]; //byte[] array
networkStream.Read(bDataReceived, 0, bBytesToRead);
try
{
   if (ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bDataReceived).Trim() != "")
   {
       saBytesReceived = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bDataReceived)
                         .Split(new string[] { "\0" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
      saBytesReceived = saBytesReceived.Select(s => s.Replace("?", "")).ToArray();     
      saBytesReceived = //Remove array elements in One single Line
    }
}
```

I dont want to use any Loop ..Just by using **LINQ** can we do it in Single line ?

My Sample Array

```
65928346897326
34623462346346
%346346
%436534
32632463667364
```

Resultant Array Should be

```
%346346
%436534
```

Comment: Your code is broken to start with - you're ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read`. *Never* do that, particularly with network streams.

Comment: LINQ is mostly implemented in loops. You can't completely avoid that.

Comment: @JonSkeet  I pasted some part of my code. I have taken all necessary precautions

Comment: @Oded See My Code. I am replacing ? with '' in all my array elements without using loop and by just using LINQ

Comment: How do you think LINQ does it? With a loop. You just hid the loop behind a function.

Comment: @SagarDumbre: So you're saying the early part of the code is unrepresentative of your real code, and presumably irrelevant to the question? Why did you included it at all? How much of your code *should* we consider to be relevant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linq is for querying, not for modifying (removing items). You can get items which start with %:

```
saBytesReceived = saBytesReceived.Where(s => s.StartsWith("%")).ToArray();
```

This will create new array with items you want:

```
%346346
%436534
```

And yes, internally Linq will use loop.

---

BTW you can refactor your code into single query:

```
   string response = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bDataReceived);

   if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response))
   {      
       saBytesReceived = response
              .Split(new string[] { "\0" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
              .Select(s => s.Replace("?", ""))
              .Where(s => s.StartsWith("%"))
              .ToArray();
   }
```

Comment: +1, maybe replace "var result" with "saBytesReceived" to match the OP code